# Which positive real number x has the property that x, floor of x and x - floor of x form a geometric progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-series

Which positive real number $x$ has the property that $x$, $\lfloor x \rfloor$, and $x - \lfloor x\rfloor$ form a geometric progression (in that order)?

(Recall that $\lfloor x\rfloor$ means the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.)

Thanks in advance! Don’t worry about the solution, I just need to put the answer into a program so that I can read the solution

I tried plugging in random numbers but that didn’t work

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you please tell us what you have already tried so far? This will help other answerers know what you know and what you need help, and it is generally a helpful way to start off a question. Thank you!

Comment: I tried putting in random numbers, but that is about it. I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

What the question is saying is that:

$$x=a$$
$$\lfloor x \rfloor = ar$$
$$x-\lfloor x \rfloor=ar^2$$

Comment: Well in that case, we can add the second and third line to get: $x=ar^2+ar$

Comment: Better to use $ar^2+ar-a =0 \to r =...$

Comment: We also know that x=a, so r^2+r=1? $r^2+r-1=0$, $r=(-1+-sqrt5)/2. Am I headed the right way?

Comment: @Mikey:  Yes.  This answer is a good example of reading a word problem and writing equations based on what you are told.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. The answer is $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$

Comment: Indeed, better known as the [golden ratio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) $\phi$. Incidentally, $r=\frac 1\phi$ as well.

Comment: Also, if you like an answer, remember to accept it and upvote it (although you probably don't have enough reputation to upvote yet).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Geometric progression is a sequence where every pair of consecutive terms has the same ratio. Hence, in your case, if $x = n+a$ where $a\in[0,1)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then your sequence looks like $n+a,n,a$ and that it's geometric implies
$$
\frac{n+a}{n} = \frac{n}{a}.
$$
Can you finish this?